# How to resolve SG0002 warning in UWP application?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

we are facing the below warning in the output window while build our application. How to resolve this kind of exception.

warning : SG0002 : Cannot generate serialization code for type 'XXXX.UI.Xaml.SerializableColumn'

After a several analysis i have tried to Explicitly add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.0.11-beta-23225 by include the pre-release.  But still we got the same one.

Please find our configuration.

Build the application by enabling Native tool chain.

Framework version:4.6 with VS 2015

Comment: This seems to be a known issue that already been fixed. Have you checked [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f9c9c1ee-1761-4ba6-8206-c21722236fe0/sg0002-cannot-generate-serialization-code-for-type-microsoftwindowsazuremessagingmessage?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)? If you still have issues after checked, could you please provide a [mcve] or reproduce steps?

Comment: we have more advance interactive behavior in our control, Sharing the code is very complex. I just  share idea about my application. we have a in-build serialization and de -serialization support. This may cause this warning??